# PyCharm: Anaconda installation is not found on macOS

Tags: python, macos, path, pycharm, anaconda

`PyCharm CE` and `Anaconda` have been installed.

I know I should create a `symlink` to `$HOME/.anaconda`,
but what is the command on **macOS/Linux**?

Or any other solution?

Thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set which interpreter to use within PyCharm. First you can go to your terminal and check:

`$ python --version`

You may see something like this:

`$ Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.`

Verify the path to your interpreter:

```
which python
```

or

```
$ python

>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/anaconda3/bin/python'
```

Now go to PyCharm and navigate to:

> pycharm > preferences (or simply ⌘, ) > project > project interpreter > settings icon > add local > system interpreter > ... button > 
>   /anaconda3/bin/python3.6

**click apply**

You'll have to scroll up to get to your **anaconda directory** and essentially manually set the **project interpreter** path to your **sys.executable** path by clicking through subdirectories.

Comment: `which python` is also a good way to find the path to the python executable

Comment: @Code-Apprentice you're right! I'll add that in. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After I fixed environment variables, it works.

Answer (score 0):

For 2020 readers, I'm using Mac OSX:

In PyCharm, click the Terminal Tab at the bottom, type

```
which python
```

and notice whether there is a `.../.conda/...` shown in the path. In my case:

```
/Users/raining/.conda/envs/ExampleProject/bin/python
```

If so, you're actually using anaconda's python(interpreter).

- Notice that `python --version` only showed `Python 3.8.5`, no info. about Anaconda.

Answer (score -1):

Add the path in `~/.bashrc`

such as

`export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`

Then, `PyCharm CE` can be worked with `Anaconda`.

Comment: `~/.bashrc` is deprecated in 2020, reader should try `~/.zshrc`.